# How is the ordering of the Geocoding results determined?

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I was wondering: When geocoding an address using [Google's Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Results), based on which criteria are the results inside the `result` array ordered?

Is the first result also the most *relevant* or are they appear in random, or?

The documentation doesn't mention anything about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, the best score is first. I don't know if Google designed it that way, or if that was just how the results were returned in my case. Also, in most cases there is a single 100 score result.